# How to disable the "AppleRawMaxCapacity" warning in mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, warnings

Everytime I open my terminal I get this warning:
`[WARN] - (starship::modules::battery): Unable to access battery information: AppleRawMaxCapacity`

Any chance someone knows how to disable it?

Google says it has to do with battery capacity, but I'm using MacMini.
And it seems that no one has this problem before

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer: [starship](https://starship.rs/) app was installed via brew

If you want to disable the battery status, you need to do the following:

1. run `starship config`
2. in VIM add the lines: (new line is a must)

```
[battery]
disabled = true
```

3. save the file and voila now there is no warning.

Hope this helps.

Comment: great answer, thank you!